# Refreshing advanced filter when criteria changes

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm looking for a VBA script to autorefresh an advanced filter as soon as the criteria changes.

So far, I've come up with the following, but I'm struggling to make this happen when I change my criteria.

```
Range("Datasheet!MasterMon").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:="Sheet6!Criteria",
Range ("Sheet6!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range("Sheet6!Extract"), Unique:= _
False
```

Comment: Where does this code sit? as in what's the name of the function?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Zac. I'm not sure where to place the code. I would say it's on the sheet where the result of the advanced filter shows...